# Can we have AsyncHttpClient use existing threads to execute code?

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty, asynchttpclient

I was trying to use [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/AsyncHttpClient/async-http-client) library to make NIO calls from my Java Spring MVC application. Since I already have incorporated Apache Camel (with [camel-netty](http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html)) within my application, I wanted to make use of the Camel-Netty's threads spawned from its thread pool to handle the requests directly instead of `AsyncHttpClient` creating its own threads.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
import org.asynchttpclient.AsyncHttpClient;
import org.asynchttpclient.BoundRequestBuilder;
import org.asynchttpclient.DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig;
import org.asynchttpclient.Dsl;

@Service
public class MyNIOClass {

  private io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup camelNettyEventLoopGroup = applicationContext.getBean("sharedNIOPool",io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup.class);
  private DefaultAsyncHttpClientConfig clientBuilder = clientBuilder = Dsl.config()
            .setMaxConnections(10)
            .setPooledConnectionIdleTimeout(100)
            .setConnectionTtl(500)
            .setRequestTimeout(5000)
            .setThreadPoolName( "My AHC ThreadPool" )
            .setKeepAlive( true )
            .setEventLoopGroup(camelNettyEventLoopGroup)
            .build();
  private AsyncHttpClient asyncClient = Dsl.asyncHttpClient(clientBuilder);

  public void makeAsyncHttpGetCall() throws SomeException {
    BoundRequestBuilder getRequest = asyncClient.prepareGet("http://someurl.com");
    AsyncCompletionHandler myAsyncCompletionHandler = getMyAsyncCompletionHandler();
    org.asynchttpclient.ListenableFuture<String> listenableFuture = getRequest.execute(myAsyncCompletionHandler);
    // Do something with the listenableFuture object. 
  }
}
```

The `makeAsyncHttpGetCall()` gets invoked from a Camel route.

Is it necessary that the `AsyncHttpClient` has to create its own thread instead of using the existing `camel-netty` thread which invoked this block of code? Can we make it use the calling thread? In that way, it would be just like a function call.